# Requesting image from proxy

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Because some images are too large, I have a proxy server to compress the image. For example: the original URL is `http://www.vikilife.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/201210178.jpg`.

The proxy url is `http://proxy.xgres.com/proxyImg.php?w=286&u=http%3a%2f%2fwww.vikilife.com%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2012%2f10%2f201210178.jpg`. `w` is compressed with, `u` is the encoded original url.

I request the image like this:

```
String url = "http://proxy.xgres.com/proxyImg.php?w=286&u=http%3a%2f%2fwww.vikilife.com%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2012%2f10%2f201210178.jpg";
imgTest.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
```

But this returns the wrong image (not the one I want). However, when I request the url with a web browser, I get the correct image. What is wrong?

Comment: If you open the non proxied image on your Windows Phone, does it display?

Comment: Yes, the non proxied image diplayed. but it's also a wrong image.

Comment: I'd suggest to check with fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) that the outgoing request and the response are what you expect. Check if your request if proper and also check if the response is alread the wrong size before it reachs your app.

Comment: Thank you so mush. I try it with fiddler. The response always show 302 error. It was redirected to original url. So I got original image,rather than the compressed one. I don't know why.